# Different <meta> viewport zoom based on device?

Tags: html, viewport

I have a website with a static width (1500px). I'd like to display the exact same image on browser / tablet / mobile.

Because 1500px doesn't fit in an standard ipad screen I need to change the scale of the image based on the device used.

So far i'm using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=.7, maximum-scale=.7" />
```

For the website to work with tablets.

I know that you can change the viewport value at runtime through javascript but I'd like to have the page start with the right zoom level when using a device that have a smaller screen.

I was thinking about using different html pages for each device (with redirections).

But maybe there is a better way / simpler way to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to make your site [responsive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/Responsive_Web_design) but as a quick solution you can scale the whole page down using `transform: scale(0.7);` with a media query like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.7); 
        -moz-transform: scale(0.7); 
        -ms-transform: scale(0.7); 
        -o-transform: scale(0.7); 
        transform: scale(0.7); 
    }
}
```

You might tweak the values to your specific needs.

More on [media queries for standard devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).